# VSTO Ribbon command restarts Office.js Add-In

Tags: vsto, restart, excel-addins

I have a VSTO Ribbon for Excel and an Office.js add-in. I found that whenever any of the VSTO ribbon commands set `app.SreenEnabling = false`, or execute an `app.run()`, or execute `TriggerEnabling()`, the Office add-in restarts and loads all over again. At first I thought that it may be something in my add-in, but I even tested it with the default ExcelWebAddin.sln, and it restarts that also. Is there a way to keep the re-loading of the add-in to happen for those VSTO calls to Excel.